# Active admin error on Rails 4.0.2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Got this error while installing active admin on rails 4.0.2 application. I am using rails-api, where I need something like this admin to manage content apart from client.

```
undefined method `layout' for ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:Class
```

I am not sure about this error.

Answer (score 2):

Okay looks like it has been solved by adding this on application controller.

```
include AbstractController::Layouts
```

Answer (score 2):

It is now `ActionView::Layouts`

See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14517

Answer (score 1):

When use rails-api(it's merged into rails 5 now),  your `ApplicationController` will inherits from `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base`, while rails admin dependents on `ActionController::Base` and some other middlewares. To make active admin works with rails api mode, your need to do some additional work:

1. Make your  `ApplicationController` inherit from `ActionController::Base`

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   ```
2. Modify your `config/application.rb` like this

   ```
   class Application < Rails::Application
     # ...
     config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
     config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
     config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
   end
   ```

References:
 1. https://rrott.com/blog/ror/rails-5-api-with-activeadmin-integration.html
 2. [What is the difference between a regular Rails app and a Rails API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101917/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-rails-app-and-a-rails-api)