# json vs html in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

have some question when generate controller appear some comment

i want to  know use importance with these line

```
 # GET /folusers
 # GET /folusers.json
 def index
```

first question rails generate `json`  file. can use instead of api version .

```
# POST /folusers
# POST /folusers.json
def create
```

second question how access create method by json

---

final question need to  create mobile app and connect with db are enough use generate in controller or use api version ?

Comment: You can only "API mode" in Rails 5+ btw

Comment: I have rails app how to make api in controller  generate json for each method is this  enough ?

Comment: @Sdadad https://sourcey.com/building-the-prefect-rails-5-api-only-app/

Comment: @7urkm3n i know this but question i have already rails app and need api this link is create api-only ?

Comment: @Sdadad i think u need to learn basics of rails first.

Comment: I learn now but i want to difference this ?

Comment: @7urkm3n  difference between a regular Rails app and a Rails API?

Comment: @Sdadad so far is the same engine, just light weight body for API version without views/assets. print middleware list `rake middleware`

Comment: @Sdadad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101917/what-is-the-difference-between-a-regular-rails-app-and-a-rails-api

Comment: i read this link i want to rails app and api in same app . i found this link  [Railscasts #350 Rest Api Versioning] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZF4_UuJ4PQ&t=21s) is enough for do this ?1

Comment: API version of Rails is meant for mobile apps or if you use the likes of Angular to create independent frontend. Allows for dual pipelines

Comment: can any resource explain how to make api version ? @Richard Peck

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#creating-a-new-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make existing action or new action into API action which can be used from your API app you just need to write following code in the action for JSON request(AJAX or API call) `render json: @user` or can use JSON builder gem which is good option to create specific json for your specific need.

You can handle HTML(Browser) or JSON(API) request using `respons_to` method of Rails

Comment: thanks @Sandeep Garg which best use JSON builder gem vs api versioning rails?

Comment: Have a look on both I think both have different uses

Comment: can explain best way to make API for exist rails app to connect mobile app @Sandeep Garg

Comment: Use JSON builder gem to make json required by mobile app